# Break HTML into parts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a large HTML source, and I'd like to break it into multiple parts. I've been able to achieve most of this task, but I'm struggling with a single aspect.

When all of the HTML is wrapped in tags, I have no problem; however, if text nodes are mixed with HTML tags, I'm unable to capture all parts.

What am I doing wrong?

Below, is a jsFiddle that shows an example of the problem.

**http://jsfiddle.net/acrashik/aDm8L/1/**

Here is the code I have written so far to attempt to break up the HTML:

```
function parseElement(selector,parts, cycle) {
    var cc = $(selector),
        content = cc.children(),
        total = content.length,
        maxHeight = cc.height(),
        spaceLeft = maxHeight,
        cycle = cycle || 0;

    function addToPage(elem,elemSize) {
        elem.appendTo(parts[cycle]);
        spaceLeft -= elemSize;
    }

    function startNewPage() {
        cycle++
        parseElement(selector,parts, cycle);
    }    

    $.each(content,function(index,v){
        var elem = $(v),
            tag = elem[0].tagName.toLowerCase(),
            elemSize = elem.outerHeight(true);
        if (elemSize <= spaceLeft) {
            addToPage(elem,elemSize);

        } else if (elemSize > spaceLeft) {
            startNewPage();
        }
    });
}
```

#### Question

How can I parse all the HTML text, even unwrapped text nodes, preserving structure and order?

#### Update

Thanks for help, case solved, only possible way to measure text node height is to wrap it, here is code how to achieve that:

```
$(selector).contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType === 3
}).wrap('<span />');
```

and here is fully working example:

**http://jsfiddle.net/acrashik/aDm8L/20/**

thanks everyone.

Comment: I don't understand negative votes and close votes, the question is quite understandable...

Comment: @JeromeC. I agree. I even revised it to help those who perhaps were struggling to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are facing comes from using [`jQuery.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/):

> Note also that like most jQuery methods, .children() does not return
>   text nodes;

Instead, you should use the native DOM property, `childNodes` which does contain text nodes:

```
cc[0].childNodes;
```

Or, better yet, pass in the reference to the DOM node:

```
function parseElement(element, parts, cycle) {
    var cc = $(element),
        content = element.childNodes,
        total = content.length,
        maxHeight = cc.height(),
        spaceLeft = maxHeight,
        cycle = cycle || 0;

    //Your other functions down here...
}
```

And call like:

```
parseElement(document.getElementById('source2'), ['#part3','#part4']);
```

*Notice* You'll need to revisit your other methods to accommodate these changes.

Comment: @SergeiZahharenko Here is a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/aDm8L/19/) that might help you out. Unfortunately, I can't spend anymore time working on the problem. I'd suggest wrapping the text nodes in a `<p>` element in order to get their height, otherwise, they will have no height.

Comment: yes, seems you are right i came to same conclusion, that you have to wrap them, but it was your clue which pushed me to solution thanks, will update my question with solution when i'm done with that :)

Comment: Very nice @SergeiZahharenko

Comment: just for info, .contents() is similar to .children() exept it returns text nodes as well! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use css to split into several columns. I don't know your targeted browsers but here is the code (only on modern browsers) :

html :

```
<div class="columns">

very long text split into 4 columns

</div>
```

css :

```
.columns {
            -webkit-columns: 4;
            -moz-columns: 4;
            columns: 4;
}
```

sample here : http://codepen.io/raphaelgoetter/pen/ehfxb

Comment: The question is about parsing the HTML of the page, not changing the layout.

Comment: thanks, for suggestion, however I'm building EPUB reader, and there can be 100+ pages, and i need to generate pages of that huge mess :)